# How to make a bot reaction to the end of the interaction?

Tags: discord.py

I mean when it went long after the interaction has been created and the user again chooses a item from selectmenu and I want a bot to respond to the user
Code callbakck:

```py
async def callback(iter:discord.Interaction):
    if menu.values[0] == '1':
        if iter.is_expired is True:
            await iter.response.send_message(embed=discord.Embed(
                title='Error!',
                description='This interaction has expired. Please enter the appropriate command again so that it will work if necessary.',
                color=0xff0000
                ))
        else:
            await iter.response.send_message(embed=discord.Embed(title='Інформація', color=settings['color'], description='You chose the category **Information**'))
```

That's the way I have a code not working

Comment: I know that the interaction in discord works only 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't respond to an interaction after it is expired, but you can still send a message to the channel assuming you have the proper permissions.

Also I'd highly recommend calling the Interaction variable `interaction` rather than `iter` since it is more readable.

eg.

```py
await interaction.channel.send("interaction expired")
```

Also [is_expired()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=interaction#discord.Interaction.is_expired) is a method, so you may need to call it with parentheses.